# How do you add additional coding for the steps/passes into Quicksort code

Tags: python, quicksort

The following code requires additional coding for the steps/passes for this Quicksort coding.

I can't seem to know how to add it in to show the process of the Quicksort coding throughout the Python Interpreter.

Output:

['Goose', 'Yak', 'Ant', 'Dog', 'Moose', 'Cow', 'Hen', 'Rat', 'Frog', 'Beetle']

['Ant', 'Beetle', 'Cow', 'Dog', 'Frog', 'Goose', 'Hen', 'Moose', 'Rat', 'Yak']

But I'd like to include coding to show the process in between the outputs.

```
def quicksort(Item):
        print(Item)
        quickSort(Item)
        return(Item)

def quickSort(Item):
            quickSortHelper(Item,0,len(Item)-1)

def quickSortHelper(Item,first,last):
        if first<last:
            splitpoint = partition(Item,first,last)
            quickSortHelper(Item,first,splitpoint-1)
            quickSortHelper(Item,splitpoint+1,last)

def partition(Item,first,last):
        pivotvalue = Item[first]
        leftmark = first+1
        rightmark = last
        done = False
        while not done:
            while leftmark <= rightmark and Item[leftmark] <= pivotvalue:
                leftmark = leftmark + 1
            while Item[rightmark] >= pivotvalue and rightmark >= leftmark:
                rightmark = rightmark -1
            if rightmark < leftmark:
                done = True
            else:
                temp = Item[leftmark]
                Item[leftmark] = Item[rightmark]
                Item[rightmark] = temp
        temp = Item[first]
        Item[first] = Item[rightmark]
        Item[rightmark] = temp
        return(rightmark)

mylist = ["Goose","Yak","Ant","Dog","Moose","Cow","Hen","Rat","Frog","Beetle"]
print(quicksort(mylist))
```

Comment: Please update your question with the expected output.

Comment: Output:

['Goose', 'Yak', 'Ant', 'Dog', 'Moose', 'Cow', 'Hen', 'Rat', 'Frog', 'Beetle']

['Ant', 'Beetle', 'Cow', 'Dog', 'Frog', 'Goose', 'Hen', 'Moose', 'Rat', 'Yak']

But I'd like to include coding to show the process in between the outputs.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to print some of the details of the inner workings, like first, splitpoint and last?

Comment: Correct, this is what I want, but I don’t know how to include it inside the coding

Comment: Why not just add `print(first, splitpoint ,last)` before the recursive calls to `quiSortHelper()`?

Comment: So what does the final coding look like?

Answer (score 0):

An example of adding `print()` might be:

```
def quickSortHelper(Item,first,last):
    if first<last:
        splitpoint = partition(Item,first,last)
        print(first, splitpoint, last)
        quickSortHelper(Item,first,splitpoint-1)
        quickSortHelper(Item,splitpoint+1,last)
```

Comment: Output:

['Goose', 'Yak', 'Ant', 'Dog', 'Moose', 'Cow', 'Hen', 'Rat', 'Frog', 'Beetle']
0 5 9
0 2 4
0 0 1
3 3 4
6 6 9
7 8 9
['Ant', 'Beetle', 'Cow', 'Dog', 'Frog', 'Goose', 'Hen', 'Moose', 'Rat', 'Yak']

So I got 3 numbers in each line